# How do I match words in each row from a column to a data frame with words, in R?

Tags: r

I have a csv file with the column named Phrases, like below. And would like to assign an object to the specific phrase based on the object description from a data frame.

```
      [,1]
[1,] Phrases
[2,] sugar fluid
[3,] they are crispy
[4,] its soft
```

I've have a data frame with following

```
      [,1]                  [,2] 
[1,] Description,           Object
[2,] sweet and delicious,   apple
[3,] hard,                  nuts
[4,] wet and fluid,         water
[5,] sugar fluid,           coke
[6,] soft,                  marshmallow
[7,] crispy salty,          chips
```

The output should look like this

```
       [,1]             [,2] 
[1,] Phrases,         Object Assigned
[2,] sugar fluid,     coke
[3,] they are crispy, chips
[4,] its soft,        marshmallow
```

Notice how it may not be the exact phrase to description. As long as the object with the most matched words from its description is assigned to the phrase.

How do I do this?

Comment: Where do you get `Object Assigned` from?

Comment: Your data is consists of `matrix` objects but you mention reading in a CSV file. While not a perfect path, reading a CSV file typically goes into a `data.frame`, is there a reason for this difference?

Comment: Since you are doing a non-standard join based on patterns, I suggest you look at the `fuzzyjoin` package for merging two frames together. (Namely, *marshmallow* should not match because the `Description` reads `"soft"` and not `"its soft"` (sic).)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough solution. First, I create the data frames. (For future reference: it helps a great deal if you provide the data in a copy-and-pastable format, such as using `dput`.)

```r
# Create data frames
df_object <- structure(list(Description = c("sweet and delicious", "hard", 
                                            "wet and fluid", "sugar fluid", "soft", "crispy salty"), 
                            Object = c("apple", "nuts", "water", "coke", "marshmallow", "chips")), 
                       row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.frame"), 
                       .Names = c("Description",  "Object"))

df_phrases <- structure(list(Phrases = c("sugar fluid", "they are crispy", "its soft")), 
                        row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.frame"), 
                        .Names = "Phrases")
```

A quick peak at the data frames to make sure they're correct

```r
# Examine data frames
df_object
#>           Description      Object
#> 1 sweet and delicious       apple
#> 2                hard        nuts
#> 3       wet and fluid       water
#> 4         sugar fluid        coke
#> 5                soft marshmallow
#> 6        crispy salty       chips

df_phrases
#>           Phrases
#> 1     sugar fluid
#> 2 they are crispy
#> 3        its soft
```

---

Next, is the meat of the solution.

- I create a function `qd` that takes a phrase and compares it to the `Description` in `df_object` to find the most similar.
- `adist` makes the comparison and provides a quantitative metric of the similarity.
- `which.min` finds the smallest value returned by `adist` (i.e., the most similar).
- The value returned by `which.min` is used to look up the corresponding `Object`.

---

```r
# Quick & dirty function
qd<- function(phrase){
  with(df_object, Object[which.min(adist(phrase, Description, partial = TRUE))])
}
```

I then apply this to all `Phrases` and store the result in `Obj_Assigned`

```r
# Apply 'qd' to 'Phrases' and store as 'Obj_Assigned'
df_phrases$Obj_Assigned <- sapply(df_phrases$Phrases, qd)

# Examine results
df_phrases
#>           Phrases Obj_Assigned
#> 1     sugar fluid         coke
#> 2 they are crispy        chips
#> 3        its soft  marshmallow
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

The result is as requested. To call this approach flimsy is being generous. It's easy to break and not especially reliable, but works for your toy example.